# show/hide buttons on mouseover flickering

Tags: jquery, hide, mouseover, show

I'm running into an issue here. I have div#top-products, which contains a slideshow. Outside  that div I have two ids: #prevBtn, and #nextBtn. These buttons are the controls for the slideshow. They have been set to display: none and they are positioned inside the #top-products div using absolute positioning.

```
<div id="top-products"></div>
<div id="prevBtn"></div>
<div id="nextBtn"></div>
```

I want the buttons to show as soon as my mouse goes over div#top-products and disappear when I my mouse goes outside the div.

I got the buttons to appear as soon as my mouse goes over the #top-products area

```
$("#top-products").mouseover(function() {
    $("#prevBtn, #nextBtn").show();
  });
  $("#top-products").mouseout(function() {
    $("#prevBtn, #nextBtn").hide();
  });
```

The problem now is that as soon as my mouse goes over any of the buttons they start going on and off repeatedly. I can see it on firebug toggling between display none and display block.

Any suggestions?

Here is how it behaves: http://neolamanite.com/sites/all/themes/test/slider/home-page.html

Comment: Try putting the "mouseout" function on prevBtn and nextBtn rather than top-products.

Comment: It will only work if I leave the buttons from the sides when my mouse won't go over #top-products.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell why exactly this is happening, since I would need to see the code the slideshow is rendering.

There is a trick that is done sometimes with hover menus that intentionally have a little space between the buttons, that are open when the mouse hovers above them but dont want to lose it the second the mouse moves in between them.
The trick is to put a timer with a small interval on the mouseout event, and only after that it should hide the div.

Seomthing like this :

```
$("#top-products").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
    $("#prevBtn, #nextBtn").show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var someelement = this;
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){ $(someelement).find("#prevbtn, #nextbtn").fadeOut("slow");}, 650);
    $(someelement).data('timeoutId', timeoutId); //set the timeoutId, allowing us to clear this trigger if the mouse comes back over
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's because you're no longer hovering over `#top-products` (you're hovering over the button), so it hides (and then flickers back on again, because you're hovering over it again once the button has been hidden)

If you're able to edit your HTML, the optimum solution would be to move the buttons inside `#top-products`, positioning them as required, and changing your javascript slightly to use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead:

```
<div id="top-products">top products
    <div id="prevBtn">Prev</div>
    <div id="nextBtn">Next</div>
</div>

$("#top-products").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#prevBtn, #nextBtn").show();
});
$("#top-products").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#prevBtn, #nextBtn").hide();
});
```

Comment: Tried it. Still having the same issue: Here is how it behaves: http://neolamanite.com/sites/all/themes/test/slider/home-page.html

Comment: It looks like you've not put the buttons inside `#top-products`, you'll need to do that and position them accordingly, then it should work :)